# How to turn nested JSON into a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests

I know this question has been asked many times but I can't seem to apply any of the solutions to my issue.

Query:

```
import urllib, json
url = 'https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/regional'
params = 'Accept: application/json'
r = requests.get(url = url, params = params) 
data = r.json()
print(data)
```

Output:

> {'data': [{'from': '2019-08-30T08:00Z', 'to': '2019-08-30T08:30Z',
>   'regions': [{'regionid': 1, 'dnoregion': 'Scottish Hydro Electric
>   Power Distribution', 'shortname': 'North Scotland', 'intensity':
>   {'forecast': 32, 'index': 'very low'}, 'generationmix': [{'fuel':
>   'biomass', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel':
>   'imports', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 8.3}, {'fuel':
>   'nuclear', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'hydro',
>   'perc': 12.8}, {'fuel': 'solar', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'wind', 'perc':
>   78.9}]}, {'regionid': 2, 'dnoregion': 'SP Distribution', 'shortname': 'South Scotland', 'intensity': {'forecast': 14, 'index': 'very low'},
>   'generationmix': [{'fuel': 'biomass', 'perc': 1.6}, {'fuel': 'coal',
>   'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'imports', 'perc': 1.9}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc':
>   1.1}, {'fuel': 'nuclear', 'perc': 31.9}, {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'hydro', 'perc': 0.2}, {'fuel': 'solar', 'perc': 0.5},
>   {'fuel': 'wind', 'perc': 62.8}]}, {'regionid': 3, 'dnoregion':
>   'Electricity North West', 'shortname': 'North West England',
>   'intensity': {'forecast': 53, 'index': 'very low'}, 'generationmix':
>   [{'fuel': 'biomass', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel':
>   'imports', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 13.3}, {'fuel':
>   'nuclear', 'perc': 49.4}, {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel':
>   'hydro', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'solar', 'perc': 0.3}, {'fuel': 'wind',
>   'perc': 37}]}, {'regionid': 4, 'dnoregion': 'NPG North East',
>   'shortname': 'North East England', 'intensity': {'forecast': 25,
>   'index': 'very low'}, 'generationmix': [{'fuel': 'biomass', 'perc':
>   20.8}, {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'imports', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'nuclear', 'perc': 71.3},
>   {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'hydro', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel':
>   'solar', 'perc': 1.3}, {'fuel': 'wind', 'perc': 6.6}]}, {'regionid':
>   5, 'dnoregion': 'NPG Yorkshire', 'shortname': 'Yorkshire',
>   'intensity': {'forecast': 235, 'index': 'moderate'}, 'generationmix':
>   [{'fuel': 'biomass', 'perc': 39.3}, {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 0},
>   {'fuel': 'imports', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 47.9},
>   {'fuel': 'nuclear', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel':
>   'hydro', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'solar', 'perc': 1.1}, {'fuel': 'wind',
>   'perc': 11.7}]}, {'regionid': 6, 'dnoregion': 'SP Manweb',
>   'shortname': 'North Wales and Merseyside', 'intensity': {'forecast':
>   257, 'index': 'moderate'}, 'generationmix': [{'fuel': 'biomass',
>   'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 6}, {'fuel': 'imports', 'perc':
>   27}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 20.3}, {'fuel': 'nuclear', 'perc': 0},
>   {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'hydro', 'perc': 2}, {'fuel':
>   'solar', 'perc': 2.7}, {'fuel': 'wind', 'perc': 42}]}, {'regionid': 7,
>   'dnoregion': 'WPD South Wales', 'shortname': 'South Wales',
>   'intensity': {'forecast': 282, 'index': 'high'}, 'generationmix':
>   [{'fuel': 'biomass', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 0.1},
>   {'fuel': 'imports', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 71.1},
>   {'fuel': 'nuclear', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel':
>   'hydro', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'solar', 'perc': 6}, {'fuel': 'wind',
>   'perc': 22.8}]}, {'regionid': 8, 'dnoregion': 'WPD West Midlands',
>   'shortname': 'West Midlands', 'intensity': {'forecast': 57, 'index':
>   'very low'}, 'generationmix': [{'fuel': 'biomass', 'perc': 1},
>   {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 0.4}, {'fuel': 'imports', 'perc': 2.5},
>   {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 10}, {'fuel': 'nuclear', 'perc': 28.2},
>   {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'hydro', 'perc': 2.8}, {'fuel':
>   'solar', 'perc': 2.2}, {'fuel': 'wind', 'perc': 52.9}]}, {'regionid':
>   9, 'dnoregion': 'WPD East Midlands', 'shortname': 'East Midlands',
>   'intensity': {'forecast': 340, 'index': 'high'}, 'generationmix':
>   [{'fuel': 'biomass', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 14.2},
>   {'fuel': 'imports', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 54}, {'fuel':
>   'nuclear', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'hydro',
>   'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'solar', 'perc': 8}, {'fuel': 'wind', 'perc':
>   23.8}]}, {'regionid': 10, 'dnoregion': 'UKPN East', 'shortname': 'East England', 'intensity': {'forecast': 125, 'index': 'low'},
>   'generationmix': [{'fuel': 'biomass', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'coal',
>   'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'imports', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc':
>   31.9}, {'fuel': 'nuclear', 'perc': 30.9}, {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'hydro', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'solar', 'perc': 12.9},
>   {'fuel': 'wind', 'perc': 24.3}]}, {'regionid': 11, 'dnoregion': 'WPD
>   South West', 'shortname': 'South West England', 'intensity':
>   {'forecast': 29, 'index': 'very low'}, 'generationmix': [{'fuel':
>   'biomass', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel':
>   'imports', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 7.6}, {'fuel':
>   'nuclear', 'perc': 64}, {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel':
>   'hydro', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'solar', 'perc': 25.3}, {'fuel': 'wind',
>   'perc': 3.1}]}, {'regionid': 12, 'dnoregion': 'SSE South',
>   'shortname': 'South England', 'intensity': {'forecast': 175, 'index':
>   'moderate'}, 'generationmix': [{'fuel': 'biomass', 'perc': 5},
>   {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 0.4}, {'fuel': 'imports', 'perc': 0.8},
>   {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 40.9}, {'fuel': 'nuclear', 'perc': 17.3},
>   {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'hydro', 'perc': 1.1}, {'fuel':
>   'solar', 'perc': 11.7}, {'fuel': 'wind', 'perc': 22.8}]}, {'regionid':
>   13, 'dnoregion': 'UKPN London', 'shortname': 'London', 'intensity':
>   {'forecast': 124, 'index': 'low'}, 'generationmix': [{'fuel':
>   'biomass', 'perc': 13.8}, {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 0.8}, {'fuel':
>   'imports', 'perc': 0.8}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 24.2}, {'fuel':
>   'nuclear', 'perc': 22.4}, {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel':
>   'hydro', 'perc': 1.5}, {'fuel': 'solar', 'perc': 3.7}, {'fuel':
>   'wind', 'perc': 32.8}]}, {'regionid': 14, 'dnoregion': 'UKPN South
>   East', 'shortname': 'South East England', 'intensity': {'forecast':
>   213, 'index': 'moderate'}, 'generationmix': [{'fuel': 'biomass',
>   'perc': 3.1}, {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 0.2}, {'fuel': 'imports',
>   'perc': 20.1}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 48.7}, {'fuel': 'nuclear',
>   'perc': 5.6}, {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'hydro', 'perc':
>   1.6}, {'fuel': 'solar', 'perc': 7.6}, {'fuel': 'wind', 'perc': 13.1}]}, {'regionid': 15, 'dnoregion': 'England', 'shortname': 'England', 'intensity': {'forecast': 160, 'index': 'moderate'},
>   'generationmix': [{'fuel': 'biomass', 'perc': 9.2}, {'fuel': 'coal',
>   'perc': 2.3}, {'fuel': 'imports', 'perc': 2.4}, {'fuel': 'gas',
>   'perc': 31.5}, {'fuel': 'nuclear', 'perc': 23.1}, {'fuel': 'other',
>   'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'hydro', 'perc': 0.6}, {'fuel': 'solar', 'perc':
>   6.8}, {'fuel': 'wind', 'perc': 24.1}]}, {'regionid': 16, 'dnoregion': 'Scotland', 'shortname': 'Scotland', 'intensity': {'forecast': 23,
>   'index': 'very low'}, 'generationmix': [{'fuel': 'biomass', 'perc':
>   1.1}, {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'imports', 'perc': 1.3}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 3.9}, {'fuel': 'nuclear', 'perc': 21.9},
>   {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'hydro', 'perc': 4.4}, {'fuel':
>   'solar', 'perc': 0.4}, {'fuel': 'wind', 'perc': 67}]}, {'regionid':
>   17, 'dnoregion': 'Wales', 'shortname': 'Wales', 'intensity':
>   {'forecast': 227, 'index': 'moderate'}, 'generationmix': [{'fuel':
>   'biomass', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel':
>   'imports', 'perc': 20.6}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 33.9}, {'fuel':
>   'nuclear', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}, {'fuel': 'hydro',
>   'perc': 1.5}, {'fuel': 'solar', 'perc': 3.3}, {'fuel': 'wind', 'perc':
>   40.7}]}, {'regionid': 18, 'dnoregion': 'GB', 'shortname': 'GB', 'intensity': {'forecast': 146, 'index': 'low'}, 'generationmix':
>   [{'fuel': 'biomass', 'perc': 7.5}, {'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 2.8},
>   {'fuel': 'imports', 'perc': 6.4}, {'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 23.7},
>   {'fuel': 'nuclear', 'perc': 20.5}, {'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0.3},
>   {'fuel': 'hydro', 'perc': 1.1}, {'fuel': 'solar', 'perc': 7.5},
>   {'fuel': 'wind', 'perc': 30.2}]}]}]}

I need to split this output into columns in a DataFrame, I have tried a few things but I'm inexperienced with parsing JSON and definitely need a hand! I've tried:

```
json_normalize(data)
```

just returns a single row with all of the data.

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['data'])
```

returns me 3 columns ('from', 'regions', 'to') without unpacking the entire json.

Answer (score 0):

You can always unpack the data by accessing the data with the key of the object

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['data'][0]['from'])
pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['data'][0]['to'])
pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['data'][0]['regions'])
```

And then you can iterate through the list in the regions in the similar way as

```
for everyRegion in enumerate(data['data'][0]['regions']):
    pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['data'][0]['regions'][everyRegion])
```

And then create a data frame and then write the desired values to the respective columns in the data frame.

Refere this to know more about json - [JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)